# Designing a Manager class for value setting and validation feedback

Tags: c#, events, n-tier-architecture

I want to write a DesignManager class that oversees and manages the values of an Item.

Item has many properties and that interdependant and places certain value rules for each other. The values are input at the UI level into the Item variables and DesignManager detects the changes, makes validations/calculations and reports (via events) to the UI.

My problem now is revolving around the property setter pattern. I have thought of 2 ways to accomplish the relationships, each with their pros/cons, hope to get advice which one to use:

```
// Syntax is cleaner
// DesignManager does not know about the change Item notifies DesignManager
// Nested collections can notify DesignManager, but there is problem of identifying the sender
DesignManager.Item.Property = value;

// Syntax is not clean
// Hard to support value setting of nested Items or collections within Items
// DesignManager immediately gets informed of the change via the calling UI logic.
DesignManager.SetItemProperty(value);
```

I don't know which one I prefer because I cannot see all the caveats related to each one. Currently, my biggest issue is with nested collections in Item.

If anyone has experience with this, hope can advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from a c# database linq mapping:

```
    public int id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._id != value))
            {
                this.OnidChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._id = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("id");
                this.OnidChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Microsoft goes yet a third way and uses properties, which within the set function fire events.
The onchanging - event is sent before the change an thus could be used to veto a change (not implemented from MS).
Microsoft does not make a seperation for each property of a class, there is only one event where the name of the property is included. 
In your manager you can subscribe to the events and validate/ calculate the properties as needed.